# Read a registry key to get values for macro to run automatically multiple files with powershell

Tags: xml, excel, powershell, registry

I have problems to transfer the values of the xml-file to the "macro", that needs these paths (content of the xml) to work with.

I use powershell to run the personal macro on multiple files and that worked out perfectly till the point I added the xml-file to read out the pathes.

[image: Powershell-Script]
[image: Error message after running the script]

Here`s the XML-File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <Reports>
     <Report>
        <Report_Path>"C:\Users\famichalsk\Desktop\Versuch1\C2.1.1.F003 KS05599 Project Data Plan.xlsm"</Report_Path>
     </Report>
     <Report>
        <Report_Path>"C:\Users\famichalsk\Desktop\Versuch1\C2.1.1.F003-PDP-KS05917.xlsm"</Report_Path>
     </Report>
     <Report>
        <Report_Path>"C:\Users\famichalsk\Desktop\Versuch1\C2.1.1.F003-PDP-KS03451.xlsm"</Report_Path>
     </Report>
   </Reports>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Please post the actual code along with the error, here, in the question itself (instead of pictures/screenshots).  Also, consider reading [ask] for more tips on how to add relevant details.

Comment: What is the value of `$FilePath` when it fails ?  Looks like it might not even be a string...

Comment: @gravity sorry for that...just signed up

Comment: @TimWilliams when it fails, the operation stops, because then the macro can`t run without the path...actually it should get one value out of the [xml] $report...

Comment: I'm pretty sure your Excel file is not named "System.Xml.XmlElement" - that should point you toward realizing you're probably passing an XML node object to `Open()` when you should instead be passing the node's text value...  It would help to include a sample of the content of your XML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($FilePath in $report.Reports.Report.Report_Path){
     ....
     $workbook = $excel.workbooks.open($FilePath)
     ....
}
```

And your paths should not include the double-quotes.